# Find sum of 100 for column values using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a table like mentioned below

```
ID    Group      Dept   Percentage
1    Science     H2         100
2    History     Y5           0 
2    History     Y5          50
2    History     Y6         100
3    Econimcs    E9         100
```

Now the below code will check whether the ID has sum of 0 or 100. But now I need to include `Group` and `Dept` columns to the ID column to check for the sum.

```
var resultPCT = from row in dtNewL3.AsEnumerable()
                            group row by row["ID"]
                                into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    Code = g.Key,
                                    NewPCT = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x["Percentage"].ToString()))
                                };

            var errorPCT = resultPCT.Where(x => x.NewPCT != 100 && x.NewPCT != 0);
            if (errorPCT.Any())
            {
                var CC = errorPCT.Select(x => x.Code);
                string strAlert = string.Format("ID(s) {0} should have sum of 0 or 100 in Percentage.", string.Join(",", CC));
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + strAlert + "')", true);
                return;
            }
```

Considering the table above, this code will give and alert stating ID 2 doesn't have sum of 0 or 100.

The above code will check sum of 0 or 100 only based on ID. But now I need to check sum of 0 or 100 will ID,Group & Dept together. In the above table now an alert should pop up for `ID - 2` and `Group History` and `Dept - Y5` stating it doesn't have sum of 0 or 100.

Comment: Please describe your task at hand better. Not with code but with words. Like: I have this table and for rows where something, I need to return something. Or for group of rows with same id, where sum of percentage equals something.. etc. 
It is not clear

Comment: @AlexanderTaran - I updated my post. Pls take a look.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to group by multiple columns, so in the second line you can do this

```
group row by new { row["ID"], row["Group"], row["Dept"] }
```

as your key is multi columns, you'll also need to change the errorPCT line to

```
var CC = errorPCT.Select(x => x.Group + " - " + x.Dept);
```

Comment: There is no need to group by "Group" and "Dept" provided all IDs have the same group and dept.

Comment: Your code requires to group as follows :                             group row by new {id = row["ID"],  dept = row["Dept"] }

Comment: @jdweng You're right, according to the Op's data, but the op did say they needed to group by `Group` and `Dept` - I'd just think they may have different values

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            var resultPCT = from row in dtNewL3.AsEnumerable()
                            group row by row["ID"]
                                into g 
                                select new
                                {
                                    Group = g.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Group"),
                                    Dept = g.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Dept"),
                                    CommCode = g.Key,
                                    NewPCT = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x["Percentage"].ToString()))
                                };​
```